# How do I get empty element attribute type?

Tags: javascript, dom, robotframework, getelementbyid, keyboard-events

I got a problem to Get Element Attribute.

for an example:

[image]

1) I have tried KW "Get Element Attribute" in robot framework, but I got none value.

2) I want to get which element is current focus. (dash line)

[image]

3) I want to get which element is on highlight now.

[image]

any suggestion?

Best Regards,

Comment: If you use `Get Element Attribute` for an attribute that is not on the element, do you also get `None` or does it fail? If it fails, then at least you can tell whether the element has the `highlighted` attribute or not. ___ For clarification however, when you say that you want to "get which element is on highlight row", do you mean that you want to search through the elements to find the highlighted one, or do you mean that you already have the element and just want to verify that it is highlighted?

Comment: 1) I got None because I do this 
'${attr} =  Get Element Attribute  ${value}  @highlighted'
2) I mean that I already have the element and just want to verify that it is highlighted

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

Comment: So if you were to do `${attr} = Get Element Attribute ${value} @data-not-present` do you still get `None`, or does the test fail on that line?

Comment: I got None @BillyBrown [link](https://imgur.com/KcpKEZs)

Comment: @Phatto that's a shame. I don't know of a pure Robot Framework of doing it, but you could try `${element} = Get WebElement ${value}` and then have a custom Python function to check if it has the attribute (I can't help with that part though, sorry).

Comment: @BillyBrown I found the solution on this case now, thanks you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KW "page should contain element  ${locator}\[@highlighted]".

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the correct one to help others who find this page in the future.